# Have item always on bottom without overlapping other content

Tags: html, css

I desire two things:

1. I want a button which is always at the bottom of the screen. No matter how many content there is.
2. The button should come after the content, without overlapping it.

For 1), the following makes sense:

```
button: {
            position: "fixed",
            bottom: 0
        }
```

But I do not know how to achieve 2 with this setup, any margin/padding will be ignored.
Here are images showcasing what I mean:

1. Button on the bottom, even if there is less than fullscreen content:

[image: Button on the bottom, even if there is less than fullscreen content]

And 2) Unwanted behaviour: Button floats over other content, instead of being placed below of it

I just shrinked the browser window here, the same result would've happened if I had more "cards" on the fullscreen. I am quite certain that this is not a responsive issue, since I am using Material UI under the hood which comes with full responsiveness
[image: Unwanted behaviour: Button floats over other content, instead of being placed below of it]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: `position:fixed` is **always** fixed in relation to the viewport, not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Add a `min-height: 100vh` on `body`.

Add `position: sticky` on your button beginning at `bottom: 0px`.

Add a `display: flex` on your element containing the two elements (in the example below, it's on body).

Add `flex: 1 1 auto` to have your main content container expand to fit min-height: 100vh.

```js
let boxDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

function toggleBoxSizes(event) {
  for (let box of boxDivs) {
    box.classList.toggle("large");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box.large {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

button {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <button onclick="toggleBoxSizes()">Toggle box size</button>

    <div class="blue box large"></div>
    <div class="pink box large"></div>

  </main>

  <footer>
    <button onclick="toggleBoxSizes()">Button</button>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use z-index like this

```
button: {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)